# How to get the 'From' address of each message in a Gmail search result?

Tags: gmail, search

I'm trying to get a list of email addresses based on a Gmail search result. My idea is:

1. Logon to Gmail, perform search
2. **A Miracle Happens**
3. I have a list of the 'From' addresses, for each email

I've tried using the JavaScript console / jQuery etc. to try to get them but Gmail's cryptic markup and classes is hard to traverse.

Any ideas / suggestions / miracles?

Answer (score 1):

Bah, 5 minutes later and I found it myself...

I ran this jquery snippet in my browser's console:

```
jQuery("iframe#canvas_frame").contents()
    .find("span[email]:visible")
    .not("[email^=PUT_YOUR_EMAIL_HERE]")
    .map(function(){
        return jQuery(this).attr("email");
    }).get().join(", ")
;
```

I should probably make a greasemonkey script or something, let me know if you have suggestions on how to best reuse it.